# Redis: Fail instead of evicting?

Tags: redis

Is there a way to set Redis so it will never evict data and cause a hard failure if it runs out of memory?  I need to ensure no data is lost; I am not using this as a permanent data storage, mechanism, but rather for more of a temporary data storage mechanism for high volume/high performance data transformations.

Is there an alternative NoSQL data store that could come close in performance, but utilize disk read/write if memory runs out; this is not ideal, but is better than losing data. I am reading/writing/updating millions of JSON documents (12+ million and growing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

First make sure that you set the `maxmemory` directive (in the conf file or with a `CONFIG SET`) to a value other than 0. This will instruct Redis to use that value as it's memory upper limit.

Next, set the `maxmemory-policy` directive to `noeviction` - this will cause Redis to return an OOM (out of memory) error when `maxmemory` is reached when trying to write to it.

See the config file in-file documentation for more details on these directives: http://download.redis.io/redis-stable/redis.conf